# Spring 2.6.5, Configuracion de mi servidor con spring cloud

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring, github, spring-data

Estoy intentando configurar mi servidor de configuración, realice mi configuración con las etiquetas `@EnableConfigServer`, es todo lo que tengo hasta el momento. estoy en la versión Java 11, Spring 2.6.5.

```
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.RefNotFoundException: Ref main cannot be resolved
at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CheckoutCommand.call(CheckoutCommand.java:223) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-5.12.0.202106070339-r.jar:5.12.0.202106070339-r]
at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository.checkout(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:468) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository.checkoutDefaultBranchWithRetry(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:393) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository.initClonedRepository(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:380) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.JGitEnvironmentRepository.afterPropertiesSet(JGitEnvironmentRepository.java:284) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.afterPropertiesSet(MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.java:66) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1607) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1571) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1460) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1347) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:541) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1389) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:541) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:671) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:659) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1300) ~[spring-context-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.health.HealthEndpointConfiguration.healthContributorRegistry(HealthEndpointConfiguration.java:82) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953) ~[spring-beans-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.17.jar:5.3.17]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740) ~[spring-boot-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415) ~[spring-boot-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312) ~[spring-boot-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.5.jar:2.6.5]
at com.ConfigServer.ConfigServerApplication.main(ConfigServerApplication.java:12) ~[main/:na
```

Mi `application.yml`, tiene configurado el puerto en el que deseo que se ejecute y le di un nombre a mi `spring.application.name` como `ConfigServer`

```
server:
  port: 8888

spring:
  application:
    name: ConfigServer

  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://github.com/layout022/ServiceConfig
          clone-on-start: true
          default-label: main
```

He realizado diferentes cambios en mis dependencia pero sigo con el mismo error, quizas no se esta realizando bien la clonación de mi repositorio. ayuda por favor

Answer (score 0):

Prueba añadir en el .yml la siguiente propiedad en su formato:

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.default-label=main
```

Información sacada del siguiente enlace:

[refnotFoundExepction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67371256/caused-by-org-eclipse-jgit-api-errors-refnotfoundexception-ref-master-cannot-b)

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/338513)

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).